# Matlab Precision is only 8 digits?

Tags: matlab, math, precision, digits

Quoting from: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/increase-precision-of-numeric-calculations.html

> By default, MATLAB® uses 16 digits of precision.

But why when I write `900000000+2` (8 zeros after 9) it returns `900000002` but writing `900000000+2` (9 zeros after 9)returns `9.0000e+09`
isn't this an 8 digit precision?

Comment: It's better to ask the question directly here, rather than link out to an article. From the SO guidelines: "Don't include links except to support what you've written. Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself."

Comment: To be exact, your are quoting a reference from the symbolic toolbox, where indeed 16 digits are used by default. If you work with normal numerical values, Matlab is limited to 64-bit (double precision) which is roughly 16 digits (15.95).

Answer (score 1):

you use the `format` command to control how many digits to be printed. `help format`to see more details. Try `format long g` and rerun your command to see more digits.

> By default, MATLAB® uses 16 digits of precision.

this refers to computation precision, not the printing precision. By default, MATLAB defines variables as double, which usually is accurate up to 16 digits. But you can print such double precision number in lower previsions (controlled by the format command)